# Can images for sites like GitHub and LinkedIn be included in resume?

Tags: resume, job-search

I know in resumes some people include the company logo beside each job they've had, and I'm' personally not a fan of that. However I'm thinking of including a link to my github or linkedin profile on my resume. Is there any particular format that is common? I was thinking of putting them at the bottom with an image beside the logo. Could it be copyright infringement to put the logo beside the link?

Comment: Assume that nothing beyond plaintext will reach the person reading the resume. Don't waste time on images unless you are applying as an artist and they are part of your portfolio.

Comment: @keshlam in general I agree with that but saying one or two images in a resume is too much is a bit extreme.

Comment: "Is there any particular format that is common" - make sure the printed version displays the full address and not anchor text like "Click here to see my Github profile"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What impact does a sharp looking CV have for a technical role?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23527/what-impact-does-a-sharp-looking-cv-have-for-a-technical-role)

Comment: @DawnJoe - That's the advice I've always heard from actual hiring managers. You generally shouldn't be putting images in a resume at all, at least not one you're using for an application or expect HR or a hiring manager to be able to print out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github and linkedin do make it easy for you to use their logo and link to them if you wish. After all, it's free publicity for them and it's only in their best interest for you to do that.

> https://help.github.com/articles/using-an-octocat-to-link-to-github-or-your-github-profile/
>
> "If you want to use the GitHub logo or Octocat to link to any part of
>   GitHub in your website or third-party application, we have a set of
>   media files you can use, along with guidelines for how you can use
>   them."
>
> https://www.linkedin.com/profile/profile-badges
>
> "Promote your profile by adding a badge to your blog, online resume, or
>   website:"

That being said, I agree with Kesham. Unless you're a designer, a graphics artist, or someone in the creative field, it would be unusual to micro-optimize your (paper/word/pdf) resume in that way.  And from the other question you posted today, I am assuming that you're a system operator or a sysadmin and are only applying for those kind of positions. Please disregard my comment if it that's not the case.

Now the way I link to sites like github on my paper resume is like this:

https:// www.**github**.com/JohnDoe

(Don't mind the space, I added the space because StackOverflow won't let me bold only a portion of the link. Obviously, only use that bold style if it looks good with the rest of the style of your resume)

And disregard everything I've said if you're talking about a web version of you resume, or a blog. Obviously, buttons, badges, and/or logos with links are perfectly fine on your own web site.

Comment: What do you mean "web version of your resume"? All jobs I've seen only accept computer files for resumes (e.g. email or upload a PDF) and I didn't think many people used paper resumes anymore. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @DawnJoe never go to an interview or job fair without paper copies of your resume.There is a significant chance that somebody will need it.

Comment: Some people post their resume on their on web site. I personally don't, but some people do. And yes, having a paper resume during an interview can make a very good impression, since your interviewers may only have printed the slightly garbled ascii version of your resume (that their system converted from your word version/pdf version/cut and pasted version).

Comment: If I'm printing the resume myself then there would be no problem having a couple images...