# Is it OK to add programming language logos in the resume?

Tags: resume

Is it OK if I add the technology logo along with its name in my resume to make it more presentable ? Like :

**Technical Skills:**

[image]**Java**

Comment: Why? They get lost in the photocopier and also the people that you are trying to impress will not be that fussed

Comment: The company you are interviewing with could be in direct competition with one or more of the logos you place there. It would be one thing to say "C++" and quite another to say "M$oft C++".

Comment: Related: [Can images for sites like GitHub and LinkedIn be included in resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65132/can-images-for-sites-like-github-and-linkedin-be-included-in-resume) and [Are plain or attention grabbing résumés more effective?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34828/are-plain-or-attention-grabbing-r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9s-more-effective).

Answer (score 6):

The resume may be OCR'ed into the employer's hiring database. Graphics won't OCR. Much more likely to hurt than help, I think.

Answer (score 3):

**No, in no circumstances do this**.

Why, because a great number of companies, even when using agencies have prescreening as part of their ATS (application Tracking System) loading your resume/CV.

This will have a list of keywords to look for, if you don't have them you are dumped into the unsuccessful file (i.e. Trash).

These systems aren't good at working through complicated formatting, adding them to your keywords will make it hard to parse your skills and will see you passed over.

I kept my resume updated but based on a word template used by an old employer for many years (looked really good in pitches), about 18 months ago I found it dropping off in interest despite being an exact fit for roles.  I extracted the text into notepad, then back into a much simpler and cleaner Word doc, resubmitted and suddenly the companies that passed were interested in talking to me, nothing had changed content wise.

Now imagine what your little proggy graphics will do, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Personal I think if a person put logos/graphics into a CV they are hiding the fact they have no substance to their experience.

Just keep to your abilities - that will shine.

Besides the CV is just an opening door to getting an interview

Comment: I disagree.  I put certification logos in my header and I like seeing them.  I can instantly see what certs they have without reading their resume.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely to have a positive impact in a setting where someone knows you and is showing your resume to decision makers. This type of setting bypasses the "generic database" of resumes (which more than likely ignores/discards graphics). Logos are eye-catching, and may cause some easily impressed recruiters to take a second look at the document.

However, in this case, a picture is NOT worth a thousand words. Your resume must still contain a textual explanation of your skills and work experience. The logos, if used, should be small and should only serve to accentuate what is clearly stated in text in the document.

The more technical your recruiter/interviewer, the less impressed they will be with your use of someone else's artwork on your page. You run the risk of them thinking you're just trying to fill up space.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have certification logos, I would not include graphical logos.  The logos take up space, offer nothing that simply listing Java would do.  A person with programming experience is not going to be wowed by a logo, he/she wants to see what you know.